# json encode in php

Tags: php, json

I am storing this `{background:"default.jpg"}` in the database in field of tables as i am taking the table fields data and makint the json by json_encode while encoding this json also get encoded and it is not valid json so how should i encode these json.

```
{"id_session":"c72b0581e7675b596a7651a7bb906438","gibid":"54","name":"Market Place","type":"S","num_owners":"0","inner_template":"","inner_data":"{background:\"default.jpg\"}","outer_template":"","o
```

it is adding the slashes how should i get return the valid json.

thanks.

Comment: echo json_decode('{background:"default.jpg"}',true); why its not returning the array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't store JSON in the database, store it in a neutral format, like key/value columns. Or:
2. Decode the JSON, merge it into the array to be encoded, then encode it.

   ```
   $data = array('id' => ...);
   $data['inner_data'] = json_decode($databaseJson, true);
   json_encode($data);
   ```

Comment: echo json_decode('{background:"default.jpg"}',true);
why its not returning the array ?

Comment: Because the `{background:"default.jpg"}` is not a valid JSON. See http://www.jsonlint.com/. Valid form is `{"background":"default.jpg"}`

Comment: Thanks Mchl , why should we not store json in database , and @deceze you are telling about neutral format in key and value what is it please explain  ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong in storing JSON in database. In fact so called 'document databases' use JSON or similar format. What deceze wanted to say, is that one of the ways to overcome your problem is to store this information in your database not JSON encoded.

Comment: @Mchl Yes, but you're forcing me to sidetrack there... ;) If by "document database" you mean something like MongoDB, I'd have to disagree, since you're not usually getting JSON back from such a DB system, but rather some native datatype of the adapter you're using. That the data is stored as JSON has no relevance. If you're talking about a "document schema" stored in an RDBMS, I'd partly agree and partly point out that there must be a better schema to use that fits an RDBMS better. In *most* cases I'd say there *is* something wrong with storing JSON in an RDBMS. That may just be me though. :)

Comment: @Rahul Just make a table with two columns: `key` and `value`. Store `"background"` in `key` and `"default.jpg"` in `value`. That's a language-neutral way to store information, you can encode it into JSON later, use it as it is or do whatever you want with it without being tied to a specific encoding or format. That heavily depends on what exactly you're doing though and goes deep into the broad topic of database normalization.

Comment: @deceze: Fair points. In most cases people put JSON (or otherwise formatted) data into RDBMS for entirely wrong reasons. However, in this particular case it does make sense. It is unllikely that anyone would want to fetch records (or perform other relational operations) basing on `background` CSS attribute. Going into Entity-Attribute-Value pattern here might look sensible at first, but it's likely to slow things down quite considerably (both in development time and in production).

Answer (score 0):

So you have a JSON string in the database and then you get it out of it and do a json_ecnode on ir again? For php you are just encoding some string (thats why the backslashes on the quotations marks are coming from).

But to achieve what you actually want, you could to decode the JSON string from the database first and then encode it with the rest of your data again.

Comment: echo json_decode('{background:"default.jpg"}',true); why its not returning the array ?

Comment: See `Mchl` s comment on deceze answer. He's right with his comment.